# Are there any sequences whose sequence of averages $s_n=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n a_n$ diverges to infinity but $a_n$ is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am struggling to find any examples of sequences $a_n$ whose sequence of averages $s_n=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n a_n$ diverge to infinity but $a_n$ is bounded. Perhaps, there is no such sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the triangle inequality,
$$
|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k|\le \sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|.
$$
If $|a_k|\le M$ for all $k$, then the inequality above implies $|s_n| \le \frac{1}{n}\cdot nM= M$, so there is no such sequence.

Comment: Thanks but this shows that if $a_n\to\infty$, then $s_n\to\infty$. It doesn't explain whether the converse is true or false.

Comment: @JohnDavies: Consider it again. What this shows is if $a_n$ is bounded (by $M$), then the sequence of averages is bounded (by $M$, too).

Comment: Oops, you are right. I misread $\le$ as $\ge$.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1